# Found $x^8$ while calculating inverse of $(x^6+1)$ in finite field $GF(2^8)$. Help???

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field, euclidean-algorithm

So I was running the EEA (Extended Euclidean Algorithm) to find the multiplicative inverse of $(x^6+1)$ in the finite field $GF(2^8)$. Everything was going fine until the second last iteration where I was supposed to get my $t(x)$ auxiliary polynomial that was going to be the inverse. However, this is what I got:
$$1=(x+1)-1(x)
=(r_1+x^2 r_0+x^4 r_1+xr_0+x^3 r_1)+x(x^5 r_0+x^4 r_0+x^3 r_0+x^2 r_0+r_0+x^7 r_1+x^6 r_1+x^5 r_1+x^4 r_1+x^3 r_1+x^2 r_1+xr_1)$$
This equated to $$(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2 ) r_0+(x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^3+1)r_1$$
But as much as I know, there shouldn't be a value greater than x^7 in the polynomial, should there? Please Help I need to submit an assignment day after tomorrow...

(EDIT)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpS05.png)
This is an image of the EEA calculations

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your question readable.  Start by putting `$` signs around the math expressions.

Comment: Changed it, sorry didnt realize that at first..

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What is $x$ here?

Comment: x is just a variable, that shows the bit value in an 8-bit vector. So, for example, the polynomial $$x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x$$ in bit value is (11111110)

Comment: Btw in the look up table the inverse is actually equal to (11111110) meaning that the 4th iteration's $$r_1$$ is the correct answer

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  On line 2 in the linked image, you have $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1=x^2(x^6+1)+(x^4+x^3+x+1)$ but really $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1=x^2(x^6)+(x^4+x^3+x+1)$

Comment: $$x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1=x^2 ( x^6+1)+x^4+x^3+x+1$$
We get this value by doing long division of polynomials.
 
Because we are calculating the coefficients in GF(2) the negative values can be replaced with the positive ones and therefore 
$$x^4+x^3-x^2+x+1=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$$
Now we will express the remainder as linear combination of s(x) and t(x):
$$x^4+x^3+x+1=(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)- x^2 ( x^6+1)
=x^4+x^3+x+1=(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)+ x^2 ( x^6+1)$$

This is what I wrote in the report. This is basically the remainder theorem, and I need to calculate the inverse of $$(x^6+1)$$, not $$x^6$$

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the calculation at the link you provided, you're taking $\ x\ $ to be a root of the polynomial $\ x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1\ $. There's nothing particulary wrong about having terms of degree $8$ or more in an expression for the inverse of an element of the field, but you can always replace them with a combination of terms of smaller degree by using the equation $\ x^8 = x^4 + x^3 + x + 1\ $. As it happens, when I multiplied your putative inverse $\ x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^3+1= x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x\ $ by $\ x^6+1\ $ I didn't get $1$.  I got $\ x^5\ $ instead.

In fact, there appears to be an error on line $2$ of the calculation pointed to by your link.  I believe the remainder on the right side of the equation should be $\ x^4 + x^3 +x^2 + x + 1\ $ rather than $\ x^4 + x^3 + x + 1\ $.

Comment: Yes you are right there was a problem in line 2, however, it was only a mistake of not writing the $$x^2$$ and I'm saying that because I rechecked my calculation twice after you pointed it out. And yes you are right $$x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x$$ is not the correct inverse of $$x^6+1$$ the correct inverse I got from a look table was actually $$x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x$$ . And I get it now that we can write the >8 terms using smaller degrees, but still, I don't quite understand why I'm not getting the correct answer. And btw this is of tremendous help.

Comment: I suggest you check your calculation of the coefficient of $\ r_1\ $ in the second column of line 5.  According to my calculations this should be $\ \left(x^4+x^3+1\right)\left(x^3+x\right) + x^2\ $, which gives me a different result from what you have.

Comment: Guys this was extremely helpful and I'd like to thank everyone that commented. I realized my mistake, it was in the 5th iteration. The coefficient that was next to $$r_0$$ was written as $$x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^3+1$$ when it was actually $$x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^2+1$$. Thank you all for the comments.